# Debugging res layout/xml errors with or without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

Following the android [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html), I'm asked to add a button to the action bar. Since I'm told that

> The name that follows @drawable/ must be the name of a bitmap image you've saved in your project's res/drawable/ directory.

and I see neither a `drawable` directory nor any default `ic_action_search.png` image in any of the drawable.+ directories that exist under `res`, I download some search button image and place it under a newly created `drawable` directory under `res`. I then update `res/menu/main.xml` to point to the new file.

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

After making these changes and attempting to run from eclipse, I get `your project contains errors, please fix them before...`. However, I'm not able to find any helpful error messages within eclipse, not in the `Problems` nor in the `Errors` View (these just show `R cannot be resolved to a variable`, which I guess means that something before compilation failed).

My question is not about fixing the particular problem described above, but about being able to get helpful error messages for whatever this pre-compilation process does.

My attempt was to fall back to command-line tools for building, which somewhat [documented](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) in the tutorial. I first attempted `ant debug`, but this failed with:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Since there are no instructions on falling back to command-line tools for building a project originally created via eclipse, I searched around to find I needed to run

```
android update project --target 1 --path .
```

I now attempt ant debug again, only to get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/programs/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: eclipse_workspaces/android_dev/appcompat_v7/build.xml

Total time: 1 second
```

So ant-debug created a directory appcompat_v7 in the parent of where I invoked it. Evidently there is something basic I'm missing here for finding a simple bug in my xml file.

How do I successfully fall back to command line building tools for an android project originally created via eclipse?

Or,

How do I get helpful error messages for whatever is responsible for making available the `R` variable?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your original problem - I think replacing 'android:icon' with 'android:src'  attribute should fix it.

Regarding creating ant build files - if your application is dependent on additional library projects (appcompat_v7 ?) - you'll need to create build.xml files for these too with:

'android update lib-project --target  --path path/to/your/project'